# shell scripting code - cant understand

Tags: bash, shell

I want to understand this code since I am a beginner in shell scripting

```
1  #!/bin/bash
2 PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin
3
4
5 TMP_FILE=/tmp/i_am_running
6 [ -f $TMP_FILE ] && exit
7 touch $TMP_FILE
8
9
10 /usr/bin/python /home/ahmed/Desktop/python.py
11 rm $TMP_FILE
```

1. Why do we use line 1 and 2?
2. I have just learned if then else structure

   if 
   then 
   fi

cant we convert line 6-7 in that structure?

Comment: Beginner's guide to BASH : http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go line by line:

1: This appears to be a defect: there should be no whitespace before the #.  Anyway it's a "shebang line" which tells what interpreter to use.  Some people would prefer to see `#!/usr/bin/env bash` which gives more flexibility if users want to run under a non-default version of bash.

5: Create a variable containing a path.

6: `[ -f $TMP_FILE ] && exit` means "If the file exists, exit (with success code, i.e. 0)."  You are right that it could be written as an "if" statement.  Also note that `[ -f $TMP_FILE ]` is actually shorthand for `test -f $TMP_FILE`; knowing this you can look at `man test` to see what the various options are.

7: Now that we know the file does not exist, we create it.  Or at least we try to--this could fail for various reasons, and the return code is not checked!  It is good practice to put `set -e` at the top of any shell script, which means "stop if there is an unchecked failure code."

10: Next we run Python.  Not the user's choice of Python interpreter, but specifically the one is /usr/bin/.  Again this is not best practice--best would be to have a `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang line at the top of the Python script itself, and invoke it directly, allowing the user's environment to select the desired Python interpreter.

11: Now we remove $TMP_FILE, which would allow us to run again next time.  Therefore it's a sort of "lock file," though not a very robustly implemented one.  For example, what happens if the user interrupts the script by pressing Ctrl-C while the Python script is running?  The lock file will be left behind.  You could use the `trap` builtin in Bash to remove the lock file before exiting in this case.

Maybe you should just integrate the lock file functionality directly in Python, and get rid of this wrapper script.  You can do that by putting this at the top of your Python script, and getting rid of the wrapper completely:

```
import errno
import fcntl
import sys

lockfile = open('/tmp/i_am_running', 'a')
try:
      fcntl.flock(lockfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
except IOError as ex:
      if ex.errno == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            sys.exit("oops, already running")
      else:
            raise

# now the file is locked, do whatever you need and it will unlock on exit
```

Finally, note that the canonical location for lock files like this on Linux systems is under `/var/run/`, not `/tmp/`.

Comment: great! i understood very well. Can you modify this concept to deal with the case where the program crashes or the user stops it in between?

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer to add some code to make it more robust.

Comment: I am sorry but it looks like python. should i make a separate program to avoid crashing problem? can i modify the shell script?

Comment: No need for shell script, throw it away.  Just put that code at the top of your Python script and it will take care of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Line 1 should not be indented; the first character should be `#`.  It tells the kernel to execute this program using the named interpreter, `/bin/bash` in this case.  You can specify any executable (not a script) as the interpreter if you wish, within broad limits.

Line 2 is protecting against the absurd; if someone has a PATH setting without `/bin` and `/usr/bin` then they're already in some sort of trouble.  However, this ensures that they are present.  (Note, though, that on Solaris, `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`, so there's no need for both in `$PATH`, but one or the other should surely be there.)

Yes, you can convert lines 6-7 into:

```
if [ -f "$TMP_FILE" ]
then exit
fi
touch "$TMP_FILE"
```

While your chosen lock file name suffices if there's only a single user on the system, it isn't suitable for more widely used programs (two people can't both use the file at once).

You can improve your code by adding `trap` commands to clean up the temporary file:

```
trap "rm -f '$TMP_FILE'; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
…commands…
rm -f "$TMP_FILE"
trap 0
```

This removes the temporary file if you program crashes or is interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first line is a so-called [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). It tells whatever tries to run the file how to run it. The second line makes sure `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are on the [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) by appending them to that variable, so that running simply command `x` will work if `x` is in one of those two directories (or some other directory already in `$PATH`).
2. Lines 6 and 7 don't really have anything to do with each other. Line 6 in itself could be turned into an `if` statement:

   ```
   if [ -f $TMP_FILE ]
   then
     exit
   fi
   ```

Comment: @user3265370 It puts a string (that happens to look like a path) in a variable named `TMP_FILE`. (That variable is used later on.) It sounds like you ought to read a shell scripting tutorial, rather than piling on questions here.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 #!/bin/bash
2 PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin
3
4
5 TMP_FILE=/tmp/i_am_running
6 [ -f $TMP_FILE ] && exit
7 touch $TMP_FILE
8
9
10 /usr/bin/python /home/ahmed/Desktop/python.py
11 rm $TMP_FILE
```

1. First line: specify the interpreter, which means execute using `bash`
2. Second line: add `/bin` and `/usr/bin` to enviroenment variable PATH, which is not used normally, this may happen because someone remove them from PATH.
3. 6-7 line: If file `/tmp/i_am_running` exists, exit. else, create it. see [this post](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html).
   You can use if-else to do this:

   ```
   if [ -f "$TMP_FILE" ]
   then
       exit
   fi
   touch "$TMP_FILE"
   ```
4. 10-11 line: run program `python.py` and remove $TMP_FILE